# Internal Client on Thruway WAMP2

Tags: php, serversocket, phpwebsocket, thruway

I am working on a sample for Internal Client + Authentication model like the one below.
Now I need to retrieve a list of connected sessions and intercept the close event of a session from Internal Client.
I want to ask if there's any method to archive that task? I was thinking about saving that list in redis, but it means I would have to re-write `Thruway\Peer\Router` classes, because the needed variables are now private, we don't have access to them to extends.

File server.php

```
    <?php
    /**
     * server.php
     */

    require "../bootstrap.php";
    require 'InternalClient.php';
    require 'SimpleAuthProviderClient.php';

    use Thruway\Peer\Router;
    use Thruway\Transport\RatchetTransportProvider;
    use React\EventLoop\Factory;
    use Thruway\Manager\ManagerClient;
    use Thruway\Transport\InternalClientTransportProvider;

    $manager = new ManagerClient();
    $loop = Factory::create();

    $router = new Router($loop, $manager);
    $router->addTransportProvider(new InternalClientTransportProvider($manager));

    $internalTransportProvider = new InternalClientTransportProvider(new \InternalClient());
    $router->addTransportProvider($internalTransportProvider);

    $authMgr = new \Thruway\Authentication\AuthenticationManager();

    $router->setAuthenticationManager($authMgr);
    $router->addTransportProvider(new InternalClientTransportProvider($authMgr));

    //Provide authentication for the realm: 'somerealm'
    $authProvClient = new SimpleAuthProviderClient(["somerealm"]);
    $router->addTransportProvider(new InternalClientTransportProvider($authProvClient));

    $transportProvider = new RatchetTransportProvider("127.0.0.1", 9090);
    $router->addTransportProvider($transportProvider);

    $router->start();
```

File SimpleAuthProviderClient.php

```
    <?php
    /**
     * SimpleAuthProviderClient.php
     */
    require "../bootstrap.php";

    /**
     * Class SimpleAuthProviderClient
     */
    class SimpleAuthProviderClient extends \Thruway\Authentication\AbstractAuthProviderClient
    {

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getMethodName()
        {
            return 'simplysimple';
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $signature
         * @param null $extra
         * @return array
         */
        public function processAuthenticate($signature, $extra = null)
        {
            if ($signature == "letMeIn") {
                return ["SUCCESS"];
            } else {
                return ["FAILURE"];
            }

        }

    }
```

File InternalClient.php

```
    <?php
    /**
     * InternalClient.php
     */
    require "../bootstrap.php";

    /**
     * Class InternalClient
     */
    class InternalClient extends Thruway\Peer\Client
    {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct("realm1");
        }

        /**
         * @param \Thruway\AbstractSession $session
         * @param \Thruway\Transport\TransportInterface $transport
         */
        public function onSessionStart($session, $transport)
        {
            echo "--------------- Hello from InternalClient ------------";
            $this->getCallee()->register($this->session, 'com.example.getphpversion', [$this, 'getPhpVersion']);
        }


        function start()
        {
        }

        /**
         * @return array
         */
        function getPhpVersion()
        {
            return [phpversion()];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For reference purposes, this question was answered on [Github](https://github.com/voryx/Thruway/issues/30).

If you subscribe to the events `wamp.metaevent.session.on_join` and `wamp.metaevent.session.on_leave` you will get notified. The event returns 1 argument similar to this:

`{
      "realm":"realm1",
      "authprovider":null,
      "authid":"username",
      "authrole":"none",
      "authmethod":"simplysimple",
      "session":6016528494456948
    }`